# How do I make apt pick a certain package from a specific source?

Tags: debian, apt

I tried pinning the `debian_testing` source, but it's not really working (I want to pick version 0.10.29):

```
Package: nodejs
Pin: release a=debian_testing
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Here's the `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: 0.8.1-1.1+0.0.0.6.a0dcf45.5
  Candidate: 0.8.1-1.1+0.0.0.6.a0dcf45.5
  Package pin: (not found)
  Version table:
     0.10.29~dfsg-1 1000
        150 http://debian.mirror.iweb.ca/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     0.8.1-1.1+0.0.0.6.a0dcf45.10 1000
        150 http://debmirror/squeeze/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
     0.8.1-1.1+0.0.0.6.a0dcf45.6 1000
        150 http://debmirror/squeeze/ testing/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.8.1-1.1+0.0.0.6.a0dcf45.5 1000
        600 http://debmirror/squeeze/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.6.19-1.1+0.0.0.5.9ae19bd.9 1000
        150 http://debmirror/squeeze/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
     0.6.19-1.1+0.0.0.5.9ae19bd.5 1000
        150 http://debmirror/squeeze/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     0.6.19-1.1+0.0.0.5.9ae19bd.4 1000
        600 http://debmirror/squeeze/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     0.6.19-1.1+0.0.0.4.b58cc24.3 1000
        600 http://debmirror/squeeze/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     0.6.19-1.1+0.0.0.3.4de0c44.2 1000
        600 http://debmirror/squeeze/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     0.6.19-1.1+0.0.0.2.f68c674.1 1000
        600 http://debmirror/squeeze/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

What's missing to make it pick the 0.10.29 version from `debian_testing`?

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get install nodejs=0.10.29~dfsg-1
```

or alternatively

```
apt-get install nodejs/testing
```

will probably work, unless there are additional dependencies which need to be installed from outside your preferred source, here apparently stable. If there are, you will need to specify them on the command line as well.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know a solution that is not version specific, but source specific? I am trying to make this future proof as it's part of a Puppet configuration which may be used for many machines.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer. Does that answer your question?